# How to pass a raw string to a variable in Zsh?

Tags: regex, zsh, glob, anonymous-function, rawstring

I need to fetch the value associated with the "version" key from a JSON file with `jq` or with `grep` whether the former is not installed. I'm using Zsh 5.7.1.

The JSON file looks like that;

```
{
    "version": "1.7.0+01e7dgc6",
    "date": "2020-04-06",
}
```

Thereby, the expected result is:

```
1.7.0+01e7dgc6
```

Here is my script with a conditional test who feed a regular expression which in turn is passed to an anonymous function's positional argument:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
# Fetch silently JSON latest numeroted version with `jq` if installed; fallback to `grep` otherwise.
set -x
if dpkg -s 'jq' | grep -qF 'install ok installed'; then
    print "using jq"
    API="jq -r '.master.version'"
else
    print "falling back to grep"
    API="grep -Po '(?<="version": "\)\[\^"]*'"
fi

function {
    local JSON='path/to/URL/index.json'
    curl -fsSL "$JSON" | $@
} ${API}
```

The above script returns the following error (in debug mode):

```
+(anon):2> curl -fsSL path/to/the/URL/index.json
+(anon):2> 'jq -r '\''.master.version'\'
(anon):2: command not found: 'jq -r '.master.version'
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 9320)
```

You can see the command is not found because the regex has been interpreted by espace sequence characters (i.e. **'jq -r '\''.master.version'\'**). That is why I need raw strings to parse correctly the regex into the positional argument.

The same error rises for sure when the test fails:

```
falling back to grep
+dpkg.zsh:9> API='grep -Po '\''(?<=version: )[^]*'\' 
...
+(anon):2> 'grep -Po '\''(?<=version: )[^]*'\'
(anon):2: command not found: grep -Po '(?<=version: )[^]*'
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 9320)
```

How can I correctly parse the regex by NOT escaping characters like the single quote (i.e. `'`) as there is no such thing as a raw string mechanism within Z Shell?

Is it possible with parameter expansion? I tried those in vain:

- P flag (i.e. espace sequence replacement)
- g:c (process escape sequence with concatenation option)
- e flag (performs single word shell expansion)

or with globbing qualifiers? or perhaps with sub-string modifiers?

EDIT:
You made my day. I'm grateful to both user1934428 and chepner for your kindness.

Comment: When you run it with `set -x`, you should see, what `dpkg|grep` produces. BTW, though likely not related to the problem, you could write the test easier as `if dpkg -s jq | grep -qF 'install ok installed'; then ....`. Actually, you only need to know whether grep finds the pattern; no need to use `[[ ... ]]` and test for string presence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zsh` doesn't perform word-splitting on parameter expansions by default (and relying on it would be error-prone anyway), so you are passing the *single* argument `jq -r .master.version` to your anonymous function, not 3 arguments `jq`, `-r`, and `.master.version`. Use an array instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
# Fetch silently JSON latest numeroted version with `jq` if installed; fallback to `grep` otherwise.
    if dpkg -s 'jq' | grep -qF 'install ok installed'; then
        print "using jq"
        API=(jq -r '.master.version')
    else
        print "falling back to grep"
        API=(grep -Po '(?<="version": "\)\[\^"]*')
    fi

function {
    local JSON='unified_resource_identifier/index.json'
    curl -fsSL "$JSON" | "$@"
} $API  # or "${API[@]}"
```

Further, it's simpler to use `whence` to see if `jq` is available at all, rather than checking if it was installed with `dpkg` specifically.

```
if whence jq > /dev/null; then
  API=(jq -r '.master.version')
else
  API=(grep -Po '(?<="version": "\)\[\^"]*')
fi
```